# Does the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{arctg}(\sqrt{1 + x^{2}})}{x+3}dx$ converge?

Tags: solution-verification, improper-integrals

I tried to find out if this integral converges and I am not sure with my solution $$\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{\operatorname{arctg}}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctg(\sqrt{1 + x^{2}})}{x+3}dx$$

Can I say, that
$\frac{\arctg(\sqrt{1 + x^{2}})}{x+3}$ equivalent to $\frac{\pi/2}{x+3}$, that is equivalent to $\frac{\pi/2}{x}$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi/2}{x}dx$ is a divergent integral, and that is the reason, why the original integral also diverges?

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Yes that's correct, in a more formal way we should refer to the [limit comparison test](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Etghyde/LimitComparison.pdf), that is for $x \to \infty$

$$ \frac{\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{1 + x^{2}})}{x+3}}{\frac1{x+3}} \to \frac \pi 2$$

from which we can conclude for the divergence.

---

As an alternative, we can use that

$$\arctan t = \frac \pi 2 -\arctan \frac 1t \ge \frac \pi 2-\frac1t$$

therefore

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}\right)}{x+3}dx\ge \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac \pi 2}{x+3}dx- \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}\right)(x+3)}dx$$

where the last one converges.